# How do I increase the size of the text contained?

Tags: html, css

For the following design shown, I want to increase the size of text contained in it. I am unable to do so.

```
<span class="my-icon">
   Club Members
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.my-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    border: .5em solid blue;
    top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.my-icon::before {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2em solid #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    border-top-left-radius: 2em;
    left: 3em;
    top: -2em;
    content:'';
    z-index: 3;
}
.my-icon::after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2.5em solid blue;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 2.5em;
    border-top-left-radius: 2.5em;
    left: 2.5em;
    top: -2.5em;
    content:'';
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the output :

[image]

and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/577tqu62/) of the above html.

How do I increase the size of the text inside it ? As I increase the size of the font by `font-weight`, size of the whole container increases. What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `em` for your width and height attributes. `em` is a relative measurement which will be based on the current value/size of your font.

Because of the relative measurement value you're using, your shape will re-size with the font size. Setting your font to bold slightly increases the font size which in turn increases the value of an em.

If your font size is 10px then 1em = 10px; If you change font size to 15px then 1em = 15px;

Either adjust your property values to something that isn't relative, like pixels, or wrap the text within your `.my-icon` span with another span tag like Dan has done with his solution.

Comment: This. You need a fixed width and height for .my-icon

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @JSG's answer, but I would avoid creating a CSS rule for all `span div`'s on your website.

You are better off creating a separate class, and using `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="my-icon">
    <span class="large">Club Members</span>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.large {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/577tqu62/7/)

Comment: +1 for not placing a block-level element inside an inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<span class="my-icon">
    <div>Club Members</div>
</span>
```

With CSS:

```
span div{
    font-size:40px;
}
```

It should increase the size of the text, not the span `my-icon`.

Comment: I would suggest using a `<span>` and not a `<div>`. I believe inline elements should not contain block-level elements.

Comment: I know the html syntax is completely wrong but its just an example to show that the text font size can be changed relative to the background element.